# how to set JCheckBox to have a check mark, or not within a program

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I am using a single `JCheckBox` as an un-editable indicator for when something happens in my program. Right now I have this:

```
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    try {

        if (Controller.c.turn.equals(this)) {
            tp.turnCheckBox.setBorderPainted(true);
        }
        else {
            tp.turnCheckBox.setBorderPainted(false);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

Basically, instead of painting the `turnCheckBox` border... I want to have a checkmark in it.
It seems like it would be a simple pre-made method, maybe I am missing something but I can't get it to happen.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using `tp.turnCheckBox.setSelected (boolean isSelected)` will check (or uncheck) the checkbox.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I didn't see that method!

Comment: Using the poster's sample code: `tp.turnCheckBox.setSelected(Controller.c.turn.equals(this));`

Comment: Marcelo raises a good point in his answer, I suggest you take note of it too :o)

Comment: The OP also wants the checkbox to be not editable (readonly).

Answer (score 8):

To use the checkBox in "readonly" mode, use:

```
tp.turnCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
```

To make the checkBox appear checked or not checked, use:

```
tp.turnCheckBox.setSelected(isSelected);
```

where isSelected is a boolean expression which indicates if the control is checked or not checked.

Answer (score 5):

JCheckBox has a method from its super class setSelected().  For your future knowledge and searching, in the Api with these components there is typically a chain of super classes you can go up in search for methods such as these.

JCheckBox has to go up 2 levels of classes to AbstractButton to find the setSelected() method.

Sometimes the fastest way to find something like this is simply with an IDE's autocomplete.